# Get database file in /data/data on rooted device

Tags: android, linux

I can access to my package in `/data/data` folder. But i can't  `cp` command this database file to SDCard. It says : `cp: not found`. I do as follow:

```
# cd databases
# ls
    webview.db
    mydatabase.db
    webviewCache.db
# cp mydatabase /mnt/sdcard
```

but

```
cp: not found
```

Does anybody know how to do this?  How can I get this file.

Comment: Use root explorer. Why bothering with all the commands. This issue looks like  a busybox issue.

Comment: The `cp` binary is not included in stock Android.

Comment: You can install busybox, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat source_file > dest_file
```

You can also install busybox, and get the use of cp command, along with a host of others. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en

Comment: This is the answer consistent with the original intent of performing the copy from the adb (root) command line, in the stock case where there is no 'cp' program on the device.

Answer (score 1):

When you are referring a file , you need to give the extension as well!. That's the first part. i.e, It should be `cp mydatabase.db /mnt/sdcard`  with a `.db` . However `cp` is not a part of android stock binaries. You need busybox for getting those commands.

If you really want the file to be copied [ Without busybox installed ] .Use this ,

`cat mydatabase.db > /mnt/sdcard/mydatabase.db` .

If you want to use `cp` , you need to install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) on your device.

Comment: As slayton says, there is no 'cp' unless they have added it in a customization (such as installing busybox as part of a custom rom)

Comment: @tai.tran2008  you need to specify the **full filename** .  Check the answer.

Comment: Awesome, I did it thank to busybox... @ngen I have to wait 20days to rename :( . Thank U