# not running sqlite3 from shell in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to run sqlite3 from shell but it is giving **error  sqlite3: not found**

```
C:\Users\karanbeer.kaur>adb shell
    # sqlite3 mydata.db
    sqlite3 mydata.db
    sqlite3: not found
    #
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Here is how to pull out database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646653/get-database-file-in-data-data-on-rooted-device

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the Below Step .

In Command Prompt .

```
1) Go to your sdk-tool directory . (Example - E:\android-sdk-windows\tools or platform-tools>)
2) Type adb shell and press enter
3) # cd data
4) # cd data
5) # cd your package name
6) # cd databases
7) # sqlite3 your_database_name.db
```

It will open a sqlite3 prompt where you can manually create a tables and insert data into them .

Comment: can you write your steps ? have you run emulator first ?

Comment: i am able to done this by following steps from  this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-448361.html

Answer (score 0):

Please review these step for create sqlite3 database using command prompt as below.

```
D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb shell
1.  # cd data
2.  # cd data
3.  # cd com.tablet.view       //(this is  your project package name)
4.  # sqlite3 Manoj.db  // database name .


/////- get result 
sqlite3 Manoj.db
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

If you have any issue then ask me feel free any time. Best of luck..