# How to get database file from any android project in emulator or in pc

Tags: android

I have develope one project on android n have made database using sql lite but how to find physical file of database in pc or in emulato

Answer (score 9):

1.select `DDMS`

2.Select `Device`

3.select `File Explorer`

4.explore `data`

5.again explore another `data` in hierarchy

6.look for your `package` and select it

7.Inside your package you will see `databases` folder

8.Select your `database`

9.select `pull a file from device`

However file is not readable, to read the file either you have to use tool or terminal[image: This snapshot will help you]

Comment: thanks :D just notice for someone test on rooted device should read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646653/get-database-file-in-data-data-on-rooted-device

Answer (score 0):

One option is to download the database file using DDMS or adb pull and then use a desktop SQLite client to examine it.

adb pull /path/to/your/db

Comment: can u tell step for adb pull??

Answer (score 0):

You can download this awesome plugin for Eclipse, and whenever you're running an emulator you can just use File Explorer to navigate to the data folder where the database is stored and open the plugin. It'll show the sqlite database in a wonderful spreadsheet for you

[SQLite Browser for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cellobject-sqlite-xml-browser#.URFQOGfw6RM)

Answer (score 0):

Through Eclipse:

window-->open perspective-->(Select your emulator or device if not selected)File Explorer --> data --> data -->select your package name --> databases --> you will be able to see database file with .db extension.

yeah to get this file on your local folder,
select your db file then on right side you will see icon,
select pull a file from the device,
store it where you want.

to see the content of this db file you can use @Jade Byfield suggested plugin, and also modify it